MapForce - Mapping 2 different input files to 1 output file
In MapForce, is it possible to map 2 different source files, with 1 common item, to 1 target file, combining the values if the common item value matches?
So something like the JOIN-statement in SQL.
And if possible, how do you do this?
I am a newby with MapForce. Have searched on the Altova website, and used Google, with no result.

mapforce includes a number of examples. These are located in your documents folder under Altova.
Here is an example that pretty much covers your scenario.
Name of scenario: Multiple source components on one target component
MFD file in Documents you want to open:
MultipleSourcesToOneTarget.mfd
In general i can say that those tutorials helped me a lot at the beginning. After you looked at one of them of each category you should have a basic understanding of what you are doing.
Example of merging inputs
